# Errors attempting to use linearmodels.panel.PanelOLS entity effects (not time effects)

Tags: python, pandas, regression, linearmodels

I have a Pandas DataFrame like (abridged):

|  | age | gender | control | county |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11877 | 67.0 | F | 0 | AL-Calhoun |
| 11552 | 60.0 | F | 0 | AL-Coosa |
| 11607 | 60.0 | F | 0 | AL-Talladega |
| 13821 | NaN | NaN | 1 | AL-Mobile |
| 11462 | 59.0 | F | 0 | AL-Dale |

I want to run a linear regression with fixed effects **by county entity (*not* by time)** to balance check my control and treatment groups for an experimental design, such that my dependent variable is membership in the treatment group (`control` = 1) or not (`control` = 0).

In order to do this, so far as I have seen I need to use `linearmodels.panel.PanelOLS` and set my entity field (`county`) as my index.

So far as I'm aware my model should look like this:

```
# set index on entity effects field:
to_model = to_model.set_index(["county"])

# implement fixed effects linear model
model = PanelOLS.from_formula("control ~ age + gender + EntityEffects", to_model)
```

When I try to do this, I get the below error:

```
ValueError: The index on the time dimension must be either numeric or date-like
```

I have seen a lot of implementations of such models online and they all seem to use a temporal effect, which is not relevant in my case. If I try to encode my `county` field using numerics, I get a different error.

```
# create a dict to map county values to numerics
county_map = dict(zip(to_model["county"].unique(), range(len(to_model.county.unique()))))

# create a numeric column as alternative to county
to_model["county_numeric"] = to_model["county"].map(county_map)

# set index on numeric entity effects field
to_model = to_model.set_index(["county_numeric"])
```

```
FactorEvaluationError: Unable to evaluate factor `control`. [KeyError: 'control']
```

How am I able to implement this model using the `county` as a unit fixed effect?

Comment: You need to have entity and time dimensions.  Your `set_index` should be of the form `.set_index([entity_col_name, time_col_name])` so that you end up with a 2-level multiindex.   You only seem to have 1-level in your index.  I can't see which column is the time index.  To use fixed effects, you need at least 2 observations per entity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have multiple entries for each `county`, then you could use the following. The key step is to use a `groupby` `transform` to create a distinct numeric index for each county which can be used as a fake time index.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import string
import linearmodels as lm

# Generate randomd DF
rs = np.random.default_rng(1213892)
counties = rs.choice([c for c in string.ascii_lowercase], (1000, 3))
counties = np.array([["".join(c)] * 10 for c in counties]).ravel()
age = rs.integers(18, 65, (10 * 1000))
gender = rs.choice(["m", "f"], size=(10 * 1000))
control = rs.integers(0, 2, size=10 * 1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"counties": counties, "age": age, "gender": gender, "control": control}
)
# Construct a dummy numeric index for each county
numeric_index = df.groupby("counties").age.transform(lambda c: np.arange(len(c)))
df["numeric_index"] = numeric_index
df = df.set_index(["counties","numeric_index"])
# Take a look
df.head(15)
```

```
                        age gender  control
counties numeric_index                     
qbt      0               51      m        1
         1               36      m        0
         2               28      f        1
         3               28      m        0
         4               47      m        0
         5               19      m        1
         6               32      m        1
         7               54      m        0
         8               36      m        1
         9               52      m        0
nub      0               19      m        0
         1               57      m        0
         2               49      f        0
         3               53      m        1
         4               30      f        0
```

This just shows that the model can be estimated.

```py
# Fit the model
# Note: Results are meaningless, just shows that this works
lm.PanelOLS.from_formula("control ~ age + gender + EntityEffects", data=df)
mod = lm.PanelOLS.from_formula("control ~ age + gender + EntityEffects", data=df)
mod.fit()
```

```
                          PanelOLS Estimation Summary                           
================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                control   R-squared:                        0.0003
Estimator:                   PanelOLS   R-squared (Between):              0.0005
No. Observations:               10000   R-squared (Within):               0.0003
Date:                Thu, May 12 2022   R-squared (Overall):              0.0003
Time:                        11:08:00   Log-likelihood                   -6768.3
Cov. Estimator:            Unadjusted                                           
                                        F-statistic:                      1.4248
Entities:                         962   P-value                           0.2406
Avg Obs:                       10.395   Distribution:                  F(2,9036)
Min Obs:                      10.0000                                           
Max Obs:                       30.000   F-statistic (robust):             2287.4
                                        P-value                           0.0000
Time periods:                      30   Distribution:                  F(2,9036)
Avg Obs:                       333.33                                           
Min Obs:                       2.0000                                           
Max Obs:                       962.00                                           
                                                                                
                              Parameter Estimates                              
===============================================================================
             Parameter  Std. Err.     T-stat    P-value    Lower CI    Upper CI
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
age            -0.0002     0.0004    -0.5142     0.6072     -0.0010      0.0006
gender[T.f]     0.5191     0.0176     29.559     0.0000      0.4847      0.5535
gender[T.m]     0.5021     0.0175     28.652     0.0000      0.4678      0.5365
===============================================================================

F-test for Poolability: 0.9633
P-value: 0.7768
Distribution: F(961,9036)

Included effects: Entity
PanelEffectsResults, id: 0x2246f38a9d0
```